# Как можно получить всю историю чата когда бот заходит в чат и найти первый хештег?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как можно получить всю историю чата когда бот заходит в чат и найти первый хештег. Например, когда бот заходит в чат он ищет все сообщения в которых есть #Задания и выводит последние. Реализуемо ли это вообще на aiogram?

Comment: Никак._________

Answer (score 0):

Нет, в Telegram боты не могут читать историю чата или канала в принципе.
Для этой задачи можно использовать юзерботов. (например либы pyrogram, telethon)